# adding drop down list to django

Tags: python, django

I have a HTML template for the drop down list:

```
<select name="quality">
    {% for quality in qs %}
        {% ifequal qu.id sel.id %}
            <option value="{{sele.key}}" selected="selected">Movie {{qu.id}}: {{quality.name}}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{sele.keyy}}">Movie {{qu.id}}: {{quality.name}}</option>
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

How can i implement this in my models and views, or how can i write models and views for the drop down list ...

Comment: You need a forms.ChoiceField or a forms.ModelCoiceField. What are you doing with the form and where does the "quality" variable comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs)

They are great for reusing forms, validation, and make processing forms much more pythonic.

You can create a `ChoiceField` in your form, and then give a tuple showing `[[value, label], [value, label], [value, label]]`